# Posts 2 Posts: Display custom types connected to the same other custom type but with another connection

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I'm creating a Tennis website. I've got 2 custom types : players and tournaments.

I would like to display the result of the finals on the tournaments page and players page. That is to say, on each page of tournament I want to display the name of the finalists (winner and loser) and on each page of player, I want to display the name of the tournaments for wich this certain player was finalist (and display his corresponding opponent). I hope I'm understandable!

With the help of the plugin Posts 2 Posts, I created 2 connections between the players and the tournaments:

```
    p2p_register_connection_type( array(
            'name' => 'won_final',
            'from' => 'player',
            'to' => 'tournament'
        ) );
and
    p2p_register_connection_type( array(
            'name' => 'lost_final',
            'from' => 'player',
            'to' => 'tournament'
        ) );
```

I have no idea of what code I can use to find and the display the corresponding opponent of a certain player when I display the tournaments for which the player was finalist.

Any help to put me on a track ? Thanks!

Comment: Please pay attention to code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could get you started:

```
function get_loser( $winner_id ) {
    global $post;
    $tournament = get_connected_id( $winner_id, 'won_final' );
    $loser  = get_connected_id( $tournament['ID'], 'lost_final' );

    return $loser;
}

function get_connected_id( $from_id, $connected_type ) {
    global $post;
    $result = array(
        'ID' => null,
        'post_title' => null,
    );

    if ( null === $from_id ) return $result;

    $connected = get_posts( array(
            'connected_type' => $connected_type,
            'connected_items' => $from_id,
            'nopaging' => true,
        ) 
    );
    if ( ! empty( $connected ) ) :
        $result['ID'] = $connected[0]->ID;
        $result['post_title'] = $connected[0]->post_title;
    endif;

    return $result;
}
```

Edit:
If you want all the losing players from all the tournaments that a certain player won, then I suggest doing something like this:

```
function get_losers( $winner_id ) {
    global $post;

    // get all tournaments won
    $tournaments = get_connected_id( $winner_id, 'won_final' );

    // this is the resulting array, init it.
    $all_losers = array();

    // Go through all the tournaments and find the loser
    foreach( $tournaments as $tournament ):
        $losers  = get_connected_id( $tournament->ID, 'lost_final' );
        foreach( $losers as $loser ) :
            // Here's a new loser, store the id and tournament id
            $new_loser = array();
            $new_loser['ID'] = $loser->ID;
            // add more fields if you like
            $new_loser['tournament_id'] = $tournament->ID;
            $all_losers[] = $new_loser;
        endforeach;
    endforeach;

    // We are done return the array of losers.
    return $all_losers;
}

function get_connected_id( $from_id, $connected_type ) {
    global $post;
    $result = array(
        'ID' => null,
        'post_title' => null,
    );

    if ( null === $from_id ) return $result;

    $connected = get_posts( array(
            'connected_type' => $connected_type,
            'connected_items' => $from_id,
            'nopaging' => true,
        ) 
    );

    return $connected;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Windyjonas! You've met my expectations. In case the player won several tournaments, the function get_loser returns only the most recent opponent. I tried to add an while loop ***while ( $connected->have_posts() ) : $connected->the_post();)*** but I get an error from WP: "Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object"